# Не удается загружать большие файлы

Tags: nginx, php, fileupload

Здравствуйте, при загрузке больших файлов php скрипт просто не получает массив `$_FILES`, в логах никаких подозрительных ошибок, только ошибки о несуществующих элементах массива `$_FILES`... В чем может быть проблема? Файлы не такие уж большие, до 100mb
В конфиге `nginx` прописано

> client_max_body_size 2150m;

В начале php скрипта

> ```
> ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '2150M');  
> ini_set('post_max_size', '2150M');  
> ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);  
> ini_set('max_input_time', 0);
> ```

NGINX + Php5-fpm

Comment: обработка скрипта стоит в 30сек?

попробуй отредачить конфиг на более высокие параметры

Comment: Время исполнения скрипта бесконечно, или вы о другом?